test case throwing error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')
I am getting error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')".
Below is the report.service.ts code
saveReport(reportData: any, reportType: string, reportId: string, reportExists: boolean): Observable<any> {
        const url =
            environment.META_API_ROOT +
            `/cat/report?reportType=` +
            reportType +
            (reportId ? `&reportId=${reportId}` : '') +
            `&reportExists=${reportExists}`;
        return this.http.post(url, reportData);
    }

The test case for above service is as below which is throwing the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')"
sample test case is below.
it('should successfully call endpoint', (done) => {
            td.when(http.post(environment.API_ROOT + `/cat/report?reportType=reportType`, 'reportData')).thenReturn(
                of(Builder<Report>().calendarYears([2024]).build()),
            );

            service.saveReport('reportData', 'reportType', null, false).subscribe((result) => {
                expect(result).toEqual(Builder<Report>().calendarYears([2024).build());
                done();
            });
        });


please share more code, the problem might be with how the service is initialized and the http is initialized, if possible please replicate the issue on stackblitz

Is it possible that http.post is not well mocked and that what makes it return null? (for example, you are not setting 'reportExists' query-param inside td.when)
